# Cannot connect to internet with Clearwire modem

Tags: internet, wimax

I'm currently using a Motorola WiMAX modem (CPEi 25725) and cannot connect to the internet. I can connect to the modem at 192.168.15.1 and check its status. It says that it has good/excellent connectivity to the internet and shows all five signal bars. Additionally it has sent and received some WiMAX packets so I believe it is connected to a tower.

I'm at a loss for what the problem is. Unplugging the modem, restarting it from software, and restarting my computer (Windows 7) have not helped. Windows still reports that it is not connected to the internet.

Alternatively, could this be an ISP issue? I have heard that Clearwire is a not-so-reputable ISP that blocks VoIP, and I was using Skype recently.

**EDIT:** I called Clear's tech support and apparently their network is having significant problems at the moment. Guess there's nothing an end-user can do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resolved itself; it turns out that Clear was having service reliability issues, most likely due to bad weather.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your browser is not set to "work offline" mode.

If this is your first time using clearwire, it will redirect any internet requests to their clearwire account setup page. You will have to fill out some information before you can use the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Clear's dns servers are wide open to forward lookups from anywhere on the internet.

So their dns servers are used by non-clear networks, which can slow them down (lots of connections from disparate, far-flung, potentially high-latency networks).

I use Google and level3's dns servers, and put Clear's dns servers last on the list.